# Add slight gap in paragraph

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I understand how `padding` works but is there a chance and how can I add a slight gap inside `p` between new text lines.

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/copser/qc8qhwqn/2/).

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-md-4">
  <h2 class="text-center">Heading</h2>
  <p class="text-center">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.Donec sed odio dui.Donec id elit non mi
    porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at
    eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you asking for something like `line-height: 1.25em;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can increase the height of each line by setting the `line-height` property for the `<p>` element, for example:

```css
p {
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-md-4">
  <h2 class="text-center">Heading</h2>
  <p class="text-center">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.Donec sed odio dui.Donec id elit non mi
    porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at
    eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

To increase space between the descending characters of the previous line and the ascending portions of the subsequent line simply ensure that the `line-height` property is greater than the `font-size` property. Although you don't have to specify the units for the `line-height`, for example:

```css
p {
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-md-4">
  <h2 class="text-center">Heading</h2>
  <p class="text-center">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.Donec sed odio dui.Donec id elit non mi
    porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at
    eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

In which case the `line-height` property acts as a multiplier, rather than as a specific length.

Comment: In which case I'm glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 1):

To increase the spacing between lines you need to use `line-height`, so add it to `p`

By default Bootstrap won't have any `line-height` set, which means is calculated based on `font-size` of the element.

In this case, if `p` has `14px` inherited from `body` it will have `line-height` of `16.9px`

whatever value you set has to be always higher than the `font-size` to have the desired effect you want ( which can unit or unit-less)

```css
p {
  line-height: 3em /* choose what you prefer here */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-md-4">
  <h2 class="text-center">Heading</h2>
  <p class="text-center">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.Donec sed odio dui.Donec id elit non mi
    porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at
    eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do

```
p{
 line-height:1px;
}
```